# gnuplot - smooth interpolation x=f(y)

Tags: plot, gnuplot, interpolation

I would like to plot a 2D graph with csplines interpolation of my data with an independent variable on y axis. The interpolating function should be in x = f(y) form. Is there any way to do this without switching axes?

gnuplot:

```
set terminal svg size 400,300 enhanced fname 'arial'  fsize 10 butt solid
set output 'out.svg'
set xrange [10:13]
plot "data.txt" using 2:1 notitle #smooth csplines
```

Data:

```
1 11.45294118
2 11.43529412
3 11.18823529
4 10.98235294
5 10.94117647
6 11.28823529
7 11.27058824
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `table` as an intermediate file and do the interpolation in the usual way:

```
set table "data2.txt"
plot "data.txt" using 1:2 notitle smooth csplines
unset table
set xrange [10:13]
plot "data2.txt" using 2:1 w l notitle
```

[image]

If you want higher resolution you can use `set samples` before plotting to the table.

Comment: This time you were faster :) +1. Yes, this is the only working option, because for `csplines` the data are first made monotonic in the first coordinate, which leads to different results with `using 1:2` and `using 2:1` (for comparison, using `smooth bezier` one could directly use `plot "data.txt" using 2:1 smooth bezier`, but the interpolation method as such is different ;)