# How to add a sideways histogram in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, rotation, gnuplot

I have one doubt. How to rotate the plot via gnuplot?

```
---------------------------
Row data.

0.000   0.0000157

0.001   0.0491343

0.002   0.0644647

0.003   0.0637064

0.004   0.063162
…
30.000  1.70000
---------------------------
```

I made two plots (A), (B) using low data.

(A) figure command

```
gnuplot> plot "RMSD_DATA.txt" using 1:2 with line
```

(B) figure command

```
bin_width = 0.001

bin_number(x) = floor(x/bin_width)

rounded(x) = bin_width * bin_number(x)

plot "MY_RMSD.txt" using (rounded($2)):(2) smooth frequency with line
```

I want to make this form using two data.
[image]

**So, I want to know how rotate B figure.**

I DON’T care a LABEL rotate.

Comment: You must save the result of the smoothing to a temporary file using set table and then plot the result from that temp file with exchanged axes, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25527267/2604213

Answer (score 0):

OP's original title "How to rotate the graph via gnuplot" does not describe the full story. The actual thing is about **creating a sideways histogram**.

The following example is illustrating what Christoph basically mentioned in the comments.

*Edit: now setting the y-range of the second plot identical to the first one.*

**Script:**

```
### plotting sideways histogram
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 2000
    plot '+' u (x0=$0):(invnorm(rand(0))) w table
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (x0+$0):(invnorm(rand(0))*0.5-2) w table
unset table

graphSplit = 0.75
binwidth   = 0.25
bin(x)     = floor(x/binwidth)*binwidth

set xrange[:] noextend
set key noautotitle

set multiplot
    set rmargin screen graphSplit
    set offset graph 0.05, graph 0.05,0,0
    plot $Data u 1:2 w l
    
    set rmargin -1
    set lmargin screen graphSplit+0.02
    set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]   # set identical range as first plot
    unset ytics
    set table $Histo
        plot $Data u (bin($2)):(1) smooth freq w l
    unset table
    plot $Histo u 2:1 w l
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]